# How to print out the foods list?

Tags: python-2.7, class

How can I print out the list of "foods"?
All I can print was something like memory location.

```
class Fridge:
    isOpened = False
    foods = []

    def open(self):
        self.isOpened = True
        print "Fridge open"

    def put(self, thing):
        if self.isOpened:
            self.foods.append(thing)
            print 'Food in'
        else:
            print 'Cannot do that'

    def close(self):
        self.isOpened = False
        print 'Fridge closed.'

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.foods[0])

class Food:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you defined `repr()`, it will only produce the first item in the list `foods` (as indicated by `foods[0]`). Furthermore, if the list `foods` is empty, calling `repr()` will result in an `IndexError`.

One way to print the list would be:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str([food for food in self.foods])
```

If you are not familiar with the syntax, please check out **[List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)**.

Here's an example use case of your class:

```
>>> f = Fridge()
>>> f.open()
Fridge open
>>> f.put("Fruit")
Food in
>>> f.put("Vegetables")
Food in
>>> f.put("Beer")
Food in
>>> print f
['Fruit', 'Vegetables', 'Beer']
```